# how to debug a jni dll

Tags: java, java-native-interface, ollydbg

I have a small java program. It loads a jni dll and that dll loads a normal win32 dll. I would like to debug which arguments the Java application in the end provides to one specific call of the win32 dll. My plan was to put a breakpoint on this DLL call in ollydbg and then inspect the stack. But I have to provide an executable when I start the debug mode in ollydbg so the only option I have is provide java.exe with the parameters to start my java program. But I can only set the breakpoint in the DLL when the DLL is eventually loaded which requires me to basically run the program. I can't see how I can't "halt" the execution to set the breakpoint and if I could halt somehow I wouldn't need the breakpoint. Can anyone tell me what I need to do?

Comment: What IDE are you using and what version of the IDE?

Comment: "But I can only set the breakpoint in the DLL when the DLL is eventually loaded". Not true. Don't know about other IDEs but Visual Studio will break also at previously set breakpoints.

Comment: @JFF: I was trying ollydbg but I can't seem to load a DLL. I have to start from an executable. Otherwise I'll try Visual Studio Express Edition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instruct the debugger to break when a particular dll is loaded.

- load "java.exe" in Ollydbg
- Go to "Options > options" menu (ALT + O).
- On the option window, on the left menu, go to "Debugging > Events"
- Check "Pause on new module (DLL)"
- (Optionally) Check "Only on the following modules" (otherwise the debugger will break for all loaded modules, including system ones).
- Click "Add" button and fill the box with the name of your dll.
- Click "OK" at the bottom of the "Debugging events" window

[image]

- Go to "File > Set new arguments" menu if you want to pass some args to java.exe.
- Restart the program (CTRL + F2), this is needed to take the changes into account.
- Run the program, it should break when you jni dll is loaded (on DLL main).
- Press "CTRL + N" to see the names exported by your DLL

  - note: you can actually type the name you are searching for on this window
  - it looks like that (example with kernel32.dll system DLL, I typed "CreatefileW" on the window):

[image]

- Press F2 on the function name you want to break on (this put a break point on the function)
- Run program with F9: if the function is called, this should break.

Comment: @kaidentity Glad i could help! Also added a precision on `Check "Only on the following modules" ` in the event window. If you have time, let me know if everything work as intended.

Comment: @Neista: which ollydbg version are you using? I tried 10 and 20 and in none I can specify on which module I want to pause.

Comment: My breakpoints aren't hit. Can it be breakpoints are not compatible with pausing on module load?

Comment: @kaidentity : nope, that *should* work fine (I never had a problem while setting a BP when the debugger is stopped on module load). Are you sure the function (where you set the breakpoint) is called? Setting a software breakpoint is equivalent to setting an int3, it will always get caught by the debugger (or else everything will crash). Do you have a way to do a debug print from you native code? You might want to try to set a hardware BP though, but i doubt that'd change anything though...

Comment: Works now. I set BPs on all relevant calls and then it worked, I have got the information I was looking for even though I can't say I became only remotely familiar with this stuff.... restarting java and ollydbg over and over again...